# Unable to run games via Wine

Tags: wine, games

Game does not work on Ubuntu via Wine, but when I try to run games via Wine on other linux distributions (e.g. OpenSUSE), it works.

I don't get any errors when I run the game, but it does not open.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question with more information. What exactly is not working? Which errors do you get?

Comment: I don't get any errors, but the game doesn't opening.

Comment: @MuhammadalJayyosi, Open terminal then run `wine /path/to/yourgame.exe` , [edit] the question and add the error you got.